# Is there a way to refine this query to obtain the date of the Friday of whatever week the procedure is executed

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014-express

I have the following query (which once refined I intend to use as a stored procedure. The intention of the query is to move through all of a `Products` table extracting the `ProductId` and `CostPrice` values. Those values are then to be inserted into a table designed to keep a permanent record of `CostPrice` fluctuations. This second table (`HistoricalPrices`) has fields defined as follows:

```
ProductId  Int
WeekEndingDate  Date
CostPrice Money
ModifiedDate  Datetime
```

The SQL statement I currently have is as follows. I daresay that the SQL to iterate through the products table could be better but it does seem to work reasonably well and fast.

```
DECLARE @minId INT
       ,@ProductId INT
       ,@CostPrice MONEY



SELECT
  @minId = MIN(ProductId)
FROM Products p
WHILE @minId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT
    @ProductId = p.ProductId
  FROM Products p
  WHERE p.ProductId = @minId

  SELECT
    @CostPrice = p.CostPrice
  FROM Products p
  WHERE p.ProductId = @minId

  INSERT INTO HistoricProductPrices
    VALUES (@ProductId,GETDATE(), @CostPrice, DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))

  SELECT
    @minId = MIN(ProductId)
  FROM Products
  WHERE @minId < ProductId

END
```

What I would really like to do is have one extra variable declaration which would be set to the Date of the Friday in whatever week the procedure is executed and then that variable would replace `GetDate` in the insert statement. Does anyone know if it is possible to get the actual date of the Friday of the current week given only the date the procedure is executed as a starting point?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Rabbit for the prompt in the comments.   Eventually came up with the following which appears to do the job. NB The procedure is designed to set historic price records for the current week. It is generally assumed there will be a working week from Monday to Friday with the possibility of finishing jobs on a Saturday, hence the negative number.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SetHistoricPrices

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @minId INT
         ,@ProductId INT
         ,@CostPrice MONEY
         ,@daysToAdd INT

  SET @daysToAdd =
  (
  CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 5
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 4
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 3
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 4 THEN 2
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 5 THEN 1
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 6 THEN 0
    WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 7 THEN -1

  END
  )

  SELECT
    @minId = MIN(ProductId)
  FROM Products p
  WHILE @minId IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      @ProductId = p.ProductId
    FROM Products p
    WHERE p.ProductId = @minId

    SELECT
      @CostPrice = p.CostPrice
    FROM Products p
    WHERE p.ProductId = @minId

    INSERT INTO HistoricProductPrices
      VALUES (@ProductId, DATEADD(DAY, @daysToAdd, GETDATE()), @CostPrice, DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))

    SELECT
      @minId = MIN(ProductId)
    FROM Products
    WHERE @minId < ProductId
  END

END

GO
```

Comment: Yes. You can use the DatePart() function to get the day of the week represented as a number from 1-7. You combine that with DateAdd() to add the number of days needed to get it to Friday.

Comment: @Rabbit  Thanks for the prompt on those two functions.  Eventually arrived at the query I needed (see edit to question).

Comment: Are you saying your problem is now solved by the code shown in the edit? If so, you should post it *as an answer*, not as an edit to the question. If not, what is the point of the edit? (Also, to make a better question, it would be good for you to define your week. Not everyone agrees on what e.g. the first and last days of weeks are, so a better spec would include details of what the correct answer is when the answer is sought on a number of different days)